# Debian 9 Stretch firmware-iwlwifi unknown host

Tags: debian, networkmanager, livecd

I'm using Debian 9 Stretch Live from a USB Stick for testing hardware compatibility.

The firmeware for the Intel Wireless 2230 was not included in the Live image. Therefore I installed it offline from [Binary firmware for Intel Wireless cards](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-iwlwifi) with

```
sudo dpkg -i firmware-iwlwifi_20161130-3_all.deb
```

After that I reinsert the Wifi module with

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi ; sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

The wifi adapter showed up in gnomes network manager and I could access my wlan. IP and subnet was correct via DHCP.

But I cannot ping hostnames like

```
ping google.com
```

I get 'hostname not found'. Ping via IP works fine and I receive packages

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

I changed  '/etc/resolve.conf' to use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as nameservers and restarted networking with

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I also tried

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

without success.

At normal conditions a restart solved my issue. But with a Live Image a restart is a bit... repeating ; -)

Has someone an idea where I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to get iwlwifi to work you HAVE to reboot.

BUT which ISO did you use? The official one which has "main" only? Where did you get it from? Can you provide a link.

You could try the unofficial  live+non-free, which includes the firmware, from here:  https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.0.0-live+nonfree/

Comment: I get the imge incl. gnome from https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/  Thanks for your link! Didn't see the non-free ISOs.